# Warning: JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

During startup of my application (Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA, Spring Batch, Postgres DB) I get such warning:

```
2020-03-04 11:53:24.559  WARN [-,,,] 25743 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.batch.JpaBatchConfigurer         : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs
```

I did some research on spring boot isolation levels, we have: `DEFAULT`, `READ_COMMITTED`, `READ_UNCOMMITTED`, `REPEATABLE_READ` and `SERIALIZABLE`.

From warning I understand that JPA does not support that, but just use DEFAULT for given DB, in my case, for Postgres is `READ_COMMITTED`.

Also I have read that default isolation level of Spring batch transactions is `SERIALIZABLE`  to prevent the same job instance being executed concurrently.

Can someone explain me, when should I will be worried about this warning? I don't know if I should do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

`READ_COMMITTED` should work fine with Postgers. From the [Transaction Configuration for the JobRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#txConfigForJobRepository) section of Spring Batch docs:

> The default isolation level for that method is SERIALIZABLE, which is quite aggressive: READ_COMMITTED would work just as well

So I believe this warning is safe to ignore.